# Is it OK if my Wordpress database table prefix does NOT contain an underscore?

Tags: database, wordpress

I changed my WordPress database table for security purposes as I always do but *upon finishing the installation I noticed that I omitted the underscore* from my table prefix (`zxq`) - everything seems fine but is this OK?

**So for example all my table names look like:**

`zxqlinks`
`zxqoptions`
`zxqpostmeta`
etc......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's fine. The table prefix is just a string, and any plugin that handles non-"wp_" prefixes with an underscore will handle those without one as well.

I'd keep it to ascii, even though that might not be absolutely necessary from a technical standpoint, but it will get pretty annoying pretty quick when you're looking at the database and need to copy paste non-ascii chars all the time because the prefix contains characters that are hard to impossible to type on your keyboard layout.

Comment: Ok yep, I already made it like that with 3 ascii characters, I just didn't want to go thru all the steps needed to change it ;-), I omitted the underscore by accident ..